# Single radius `border-radius` as percent of specific side

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I need the `border-radius` of a `div` to change based on the dimensions of the `div` - but not to go elliptical, or form a pill shape. For example, a `div` with a width,height of 250,35 should have a `border-radius` of `7px`, while one of 280,70 should have a `border-radius` of `15px` - always 20% of the height, but always using the circular rounding. In another section of the website I need the border radius to equal `min(width, height)/5`. How can I accomplish this without JavaScript?

In all cases the width and height are arbitrary. My current solution is to require an explicit `border-radius` on elements which do not follow the default sizes, which would not permit resizing.

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
.two {
  width: 280px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  line-height: 70px;
}
.three {
  border-radius: 20%;
}
.four {
  border-radius: 999px;
}
.five {
  /* calculated from initial values, note that they are wrong with the larger size */
  border-radius: 2.8%/20%;
  width: 280px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box one">yes</div>
<div class="box two">yes</div>
<div class="box three">no</div>
<div class="box four">no</div>
<div class="box five">no</div>
```

Comment: You'd probably have to use all 8 border-radius values - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: @Paulie_D: I was under the impression there were only 4 - `border-top-left-radius`, etc. Regardless, the first value of each as a percentage will not respect the other dimension, as I understand the spec.

Comment: Paulie's solution is the closest you can come without script.

Comment: After a second thought, are you creating this dynamically?

Comment: @LGSon: Yes, all elements are being created dynamically using JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can't do `min(width, height) / 5`, but using `calc()`, like in this sample, might be a way to get as close as possible to what you want without script?

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: calc(35px * 0.2) / calc(35px * 0.2);
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
.two {
  width: 280px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: calc(70px * 0.2) / calc(70px * 0.2);
  line-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box one">yes</div>
<div class="box two">yes</div>
```

Where the `border-radius` can be shortened to

```css
  border-radius: calc(35px * 0.2);
```

```
  border-radius: calc(70px * 0.2);
```

Comment: True, and it's slightly more self-documenting than `border-radius: 7px; /* width / 5 */`, which is what I have. I've been avoiding `calc` as less cross-browser compliant, but it appears to be supported well enough.

Comment: Going to mark this as accepted - just discovered I was using 70/5 = 15, which is not correct. I would have been correct had I used `calc`, and this will ease the transition to a CSS preprocessor should we do so.

Comment: @Iiridayn And if you create the element's dynamically, you could also override CSS values with inline style, where you do the math during the creation of the element.

Comment: The problem with that is that the width of the element should (ideally) be uniquely specified in the CSS, so any changes to the layout need only modify the CSS and not an associated JS file.

Comment: @Iiridayn True, though sometimes one forget the possibility to combine the two, so just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 4):

There are 8 border-radius values to use here as the corner is an ellipsis not a circle (although it can be):

[**MDN Link**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

> border-top-left-radius:     1em 5em;
>
> border-top-right-radius:    1em 5em;
>
> border-bottom-right-radius: 1em 5em;
>
> border-bottom-left-radius:  1em 5em;

Judging from your question it appears that the element has a ratio of 4:1 so we can apply the same to the border-radius

```
.box {
  border-radius: 5%/20%;
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 5%/20%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
.two {
  width: 280px;
  height: 70px;
}
.three {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
}
.four {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box one">yes</div>
<div class="box two">yes</div>

<div class="box three">yes</div>
<div class="box four">yes</div>
```

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to show why that approach doesn't work - the element does _not_ have a fixed 4:1 ratio, and can change its ratio dynamically.